# Building a Feature Similar to Qlone

Tags: 3d, scanning, unity, augmented-reality

I’m trying to build a 3D scanning feature into a marker-based AR app. I’m aiming for functionality similar to the Qlone app. The user places an object on the marker and rotates it to scan. The app then outputs an OBJ file. I’m building this in Unity. But mostly just curious if anyone has any libraries or APIs to suggest that would help me accomplish this.

Comment: We can 't help you with ideas, as those are off-topic, but we could, for instance, recommend a library if you askde for one. Best read [ask]

Comment: Mawg, that's exactly what I'm asking for.

Comment: It is now, after being prompted :-) NP, it's all good now & let's hope for a good answer

Comment: Alas, I can't help, but the question is on topic now and I hope that you get a good answer